# Multiple Layers in PDF

Tags: inkscape, layers, pdf, export

I've created a page using Inkscape and I exported it to PDF. The image has about 5 layers. The image is fine when I open it using preview - I can see all of the layers.

However when I upload the image (I need to get it on Google Drive) for some reason it loses all but one layer. I tried merging the layers using the paste in place option, however the images on the page become really low-res! The same happens when I export to PNG.

Is there any way I can export this page to a PDF with only one layer? So far, grouping the images hasn't worked either.

I'm a beginner so I have no idea what to do and I have wasted so much time trying to figure this out! 
Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1):

Inkscape uses standard SVG groups to make layers by simply adding a property: "inkscape:groupmode = layer" to a group's properties. Outside of Inkscape, like say, in a pdf reader, they are just regular SVG groups. You can collapse the layers by going to each layer in turn starting with the topmost, Edit -> Selecting All (CONTROL A), grouping the layer Object -> Group (CONTROL+G), then Layer -> Move Selection to layer Below (SHIFT + PAGE DOWN).

When you export to a format like .png Inkscape will convert the image from a collection of vectors to pixel values. If you do this via File -> Export PNG Image the default resolution will be used (usually 90 dpi). However you can open up an export dialogue that will allow you to edit more of the settings for exporting by pressing SHIFT + CONTROL + E

Most OS's use 72dpi for their own GUI screen output. So if you intend your image to be viewed electronically, as part of a webpage, 100 dpi will look very crisp no noticible loading delay.

For paper 300 - 600 dpi will look crisp enough on A4. Ideally what your looking for is a balance between file size and resolution